# Implementing Promise in Winston Logging Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, winston

How Can I implement Promise in my logging(code below)

```
function logger(logFile) {
    return createLogger({
        level: loggerLevel === 'undefined' ? 'debug' : loggerLevel,
        format: format.combine(
            format.timestamp({
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
            }),
            format.printf(info => `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`)),
        transports: [new transports.File({ filename: path.join(logDir, logFile) })]
    });
}

module.exports.logger = logger;
```

And how to use it as an async/ await in the caller of this logger (code sample as below)

```
const loggerForXYZ = logger('XYZ.log');
loggerForXYZ .log('info', 'test message log');
```

Comment: may I know why you need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the logging part in `Promise.resolve`. Something like this.

```
log({ level, message } : {level: string, message: string }) {
    LoggerService.bottleneck.schedule({}, () => {
      return Promise.resolve(LoggerService.getLogger().log({ level, message }));
    });
  }
```

Reference - https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1364#issuecomment-398404761

It talks about how to use `bottleneck` and `promises`